# Automate phone calls in ubuntu

Tags: usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I have a mobile broadband usb modem (huawei e1731) and this modem supports phone calls. Is there any application in ubuntu which can be used make make calls from my modem?
Is there any way to automate the calls i.e, the call should end if the user is busy and should redial.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any software that allows you to make calls from a sim card in a mobile broadband USB modem. To the best of my knowledge,although phone call support is available with Gammu, it's hardware dependent and according to this page http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/5335/ your device is only supported for SMS. To use that you can install Gammu. Gammu is a command line utility with a GUI front end named Wammu.

If you wish to install Wammu and the most recent version of Gammu (which is needed for Wammu)

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nijel/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wammu gammu`

If installing its important to set wammu config properly with the best information found here http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/config/ with reference to your device http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/5335/

Answer (score 0):

There might be an application out there but... In many countries it is illegal to make automated calls so that could be the reason for not finding any applications.

I used to work in a firm that considered using such an application (we had an expensive IBM system that was able to make such calls) but for all the uses we had in mind that was illegal.